# Javascript - Create download link from FileReader or base64

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I'm using the following code to onLoad of FileReader to create a  tag and put inside the href the result from FileReader. Which is a base64 string.

```
   let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(myInputTypeFile.files[0])

    reader.onloadend = (e) => {
        let file
        for (let i = 0; i < attachInput.files.length; i++) {
            file = attachInput.files[i]

            if (file.type === 'application/pdf'){
                let anchor = document.createElement('a')
                anchor.setAttribute('class', 'q-attached-file')
                anchor.setAttribute('title', file.name)
                anchor.setAttribute('href', reader.result)
                anchor.innerText = file.name
                myElement.appendChild(anchor)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the html produced: [image]

But when I click on the element I just see 'about:blank' loaded on browser.

## UPDATE

this how the reader.result string is in console.log()
[image]

Comment: Base64 strings for the `href` are perfectly valid - are you sure that your Base64 is indeed correct? Are you also sure that you have a PDF Viewer assigned to your 'Open With' for your browser?

Comment: kinda looks like your data uri is missing a ",". Here is data uri format from mozilla documentation: data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Probably not your problem but I always like to start with the small stuff first.

Comment: @ObsidianAge pls see the update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your user is in a browser that supports the [download attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp), you can add it to your anchor tag.

```
<a download href="...">
```

However not all browsers support the download attribute. Check [the support tables](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download).

There is a lib that does some tricky stuff to sidestep some of the differences between browsers. If you don't mind a few extra kb, try using [DownloadJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs).

Comment: crazy somehow its working now, it wasn't working before. Thanks will make it work for ios and IE11 with the other lib